# Discord.js v12 How to make commands only work in a certain server?

Tags: javascript, server, command, discord

I am trying to make some "commands" work only for a specific server, so when used in a different server it would say something like `This command can only be used in [GUILD] server.`
Let me know if anyone has any solutions. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before executing your command's function, you can check this :

```
if (message.guild.id !== 'TheIdOfYourGuild') return message.reply('This command can only be used in another server.');
```